# How would the god of ever-changing have followers?

Tags: religion

I'm having difficultly in thinking ways of how could this type of god gain worshipers. The god is ever changing, chaotic and random. The god has send his divine book for his followers to follow. But like god the divine book is also ever changing, random and chaotic. The followers don't know when the divine book would change. It might change next minute, next year or even keep changing till it stops changing. As this god divine will ever changing he can become benevolent god or malevolent god or both. I don't know how such god can be followed without him being inducing his nature to his followers. I want you guys to give me ideas to how to follow such god. But here's a thing I don't want followers to stagnate and create different religions from old divine books or go different breach religions like real world.

Comment: [Discordianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discordianism). And the divine book is of course [*Principia Discordia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Discordia) by Malaclypse the Younger and Lord Omar Khayyam Ravenhurst (real names Greg Hill and Kerry Wendell Thornley).

Comment: I'm don't think this is this sort of question is not allowed here.
You can go https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help
And this link is great for enplaning 
What topics can I ask about here? 
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
For a lot of useful stuff.
And since example help check other question and see what is going on there, to get a better understanding of how the site work.

Comment: For the record, I came within an inch of voting to close this question, but chose not to because I believe you have reasonably scoped your question such that it is an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) rather than an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609). For the record, be careful when asking us to "give [you] ideas" because that's a phrase that triggers our "close that question!" reflex. Raw idea fishing isn't a good fit here. (See [tour] and [help], please.)

Answer (score 1):

**Regular testing.**

If your God is insane, then you obviously don't want to be hurt by their insane whims. That said, you can use such a God.

Every minute, the high priests check the book, checking key passages for particular changes. Once they received the answer they note down on a book what mood God is in then. Are they in a generous mood? Make lots of requests, ask for help, ask for quick resolutions to problems. Are they in a vengeful mood? Prepare for storms, prepare for plagues of locusts, offer appeasing sacrifices.

**Some constant nature is needed.**

If their nature is truly unpredictable then schisms will be regular. But if there are some common aspects then a rigorous canon will form. Perhaps they can have some common personalities. Imagine a god with Dissociative identity disorder. They have personalities which have predictable and reliable responses. There would be a reliable canon about how to act around each personality and how to reliably get goodies and avoid vengeance.

Of course, there could be shifts. A personality could vanish, or a merged personality could form, or a new personality could form. Such a change would cause a seismic shift in the church.

**They need to treat the god right.**

The wrong act could lead to terrible consequences. Suppose God is in a vengenful mood. The priests know that the best way to treat god at this time is to have some of their chosen followers sing praise, send delicious sacrifices, and to minimize demands. If people chose to have a schism and pray anyway, they could anger God enough to get smited, and the smiting may hurt others. As such there will be strong pressure for everyone to obey religious rules.

Likewise, the right act could give massive rewards. Suppose they know that their God is currently generous, to the first 10 prayers given. Those prayers better be big. If people pray for bigger genitals or a loaf of bread the nation will be much weaker than if the approved priests pray for a miracle of manna to be constant in a place, or for a magical wand of genitalia growth with endless uses.

You would likely have bells, signalling everyone to do a particular thing, depending on the book's contents. Pray, hide, offer praise, ask for things, start possession protocol. Management would be important.

Answer (score 1):

**Rule #1 of engineering religions: people will believe anything**

That's because people believe for many different reasons. Think about it, we have the [Pastafarians](https://www.vox.com/2019/9/22/20875562/separation-church-state-pastafarian-satanic-temple-establishment-flying-spaghetti-monster) ("adherents" of the Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster) and we have Christians, Satanists, Ancestor worshippers, Pagans, Witches... Granted, most if not all of those organizations have some form of orderly process... but I assert that it is not necessary to be orderly (and lawful is irrelevant, after all, the god creates the laws, right?).

So, what kinds of people would gladly align themselves with your god?

- Psychopaths
- Anarchists
- Survivalists
- The Devout Who Are Rejected of All Other Religions

And, of course...

- Those who would be Pastafarians, if only to demonstrate the absurdity of devoting oneself to such a god.

Answer (score 0):

**There is everything.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles_(album)

[image: white album]

> In The Sunday Times, Derek Jewell... concluded: "Musically, there is beauty, horror,
> surprise, chaos, order. And that is the world; and that is what The
> Beatles are on about. Created by, creating for, their age.

So too your god.  Anything is possible.  And that is the world.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a driving force behind this god? What is the guiding principle on which he operates even if the actions seem haphazard? Maybe that could be the starting point to show that there is a method to his madness.

Once that is established, even if it remains unknown to the followers, they know they have to abide by his rules so as to not provoke his ire.

It's a bit like an unhealthy parent-child relationship when the parent says 'do as I say, not as I do'. The consequences for disobeying the god could be swift and dangerous. So people toe the line he has set and wait for further instructions.